# Ambient Air Temperature

Tags: chevrolet, sensor, temperature, silverado

Put a plow on my 2014 1500 Silverado after driving for about 20 minutes temperature outside reads over a hundred can i reposition sensor or remove it.

Comment: Is the plow blocking air flow across the radiator?

Comment: I wouldn't think the plow would affect it. The ambient air temp sensor is typically in the air intake system. Is the plow is blocking the intake?

Comment: @Spivonious - I think you're thinking of the Air Intake Temperature sensor. The ambient air temp sensor is a completely different beast and is [located on the cross bracing in front of the radiator on the right hand side of the vehicle (behind the grill)](https://www.gm-trucks.com/forums/uploads/monthly_12_2016/post-151671-0-79276600-1482172151.jpg).

Comment: Depending on year and make there can be up to 3 ambient temp sensors, I assume it is the one in front of the radiator. the word ambient has nothing to do with its location but is a term meaning " an encompassing atmosphere" which can be inside the vehicle, outside the vehicle, in the intake manifold, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The ambient air temp sensor is located right in the center of the grill, in front of radiator/ air conditioning condenser. Its placed there because in normal vehicle driving (at speeds greater than two miles per hour) that's the best place to sample ambient air flow. Typical sensors look like this:

[image: typical air temp sensor]

There is a pretty hefty algorithm tied to that sensor, related to vehicle speed. When vehicle speed = zero, the system monitors that sensor but ignores the reading. At vehicle stop hot air comes off the radiator and migrates car forward. Obviously heat from the radiator messes up that sensor’s ability to read ambient temperature accurately.

And yes, that big snow plow halts normal air flow thru the front of the vehicle. Unfortunately there is no good way to get to that algorithm to add (if using snow plow ignore the reading.)

One thing we used to do during vehicle instrumentation and testing was add a temp sensor to the outside roof of the vehicle. We’d place a [thermistor sensor](https://www.teamwavelength.com/thermistor-basics/) in the center of a six inch long piece of plastic drain pipe. That way we’d always have perfect ambient temperature reading regardless of vehicle speed. The drain pipe kept the sunload from messing up the the sensor reading. It was ugly, but it worked great.  No algorithm / engine control computer interface required.

The sensor is a simple two wire thermistor, so yes, you can totally relocate it.  Not quite sure where to locate it to, but do know you have to keep the sun off. You need clean air flow for accuracy.  Were it me, [I'd carry one of these,](https://amzn.to/2U3rupv) and ignore the reading on the dash when using the plow.   That thermometer makes a handy tool to have around the home.

Comment: [This is what it looks like on the Silverado](https://www.gm-trucks.com/forums/uploads/monthly_12_2016/post-151671-0-79276600-1482172151.jpg).